# Count time between send Ajax request and receive answer

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, xmlhttprequest

Is there a method to get time between send request and receive answer or do I need to do it manually?

Framework: Vanilla JS

Regards, Matt

Comment: Thought I'd warn you in advance that if you end up using Date.now(), it doesn't work on some IE versions.

Comment: well if you r using Ajax Call you just see the time before the ajax call and when success or error and count it then

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately No.

You have to do it manually.Here is a [sample code and article](http://ditio.net/2008/08/06/detect-connection-speed-with-javascript/).

And the technique is

```
 var duration = (endTime - startTime)/1000;
```

And here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/tEFpC/2/)